# compiling libvpx on ubuntu taking long time

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-12.04, libvpx

I have cloned libvpx and run the following commands:

```
$ git clone http://git.chromium.org/webm/libvpx.git
$ cd libvpx
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

After running `make`, it has taken 1 hour to compile and it is still running.
I noticed it shows the same files over and over in the terminal.

I have searched on google but I couldn't find anything useful.

What should I do?

Comment: @shahbaz you have good knowledge and experience try help me.

Comment: I know how to properly write in English and tag questions. I don't know what libvpx is at all.

Comment: yeah I understand but I am also using it first time. please try the same steps on your side, If you have time.

Comment: Randomly polling individual users is no way to get popular here. Write the question as clearly as you can, make sure it has correct tags, and wait.

Comment: You might want to include a pertinent snippet out of the `make` output. Otherwise, we can't guess what's wrong without repeating the entire process, which not many users are willing to do.

Comment: If make is rebuilding the same files again and again then I believe that means you have clock problems on your system and/or with the original timestamps of the files themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If make is rebuilding the same files again and again then I believe that means you have clock problems on your system and/or with the original timestamps of the files themselves.